# Swipe menu, movable header items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

**The Guardian** (UK newspaper) has an android app with a swipe navigation menu which I would like to implement in my HTML5 app.

If you click on an article it has a **header** like this and **this**:

[image: header]
[image: this]
(Can somebody who knows how please make these smaller?)

---

When you swipe left and right the html slide changes and the **header item slides along**, **knocking away the previous item** on the list.

Are there any pre-existing **javascript plugins** to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an existing java script library [Hammar.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) that you might want to look at.

Using it you can define event handlers in the following fashion.

```
Hammer(el).on("swipeleft", function() {
    alert('you swiped left!');
});
```